# Order of Automorphism group of a group of prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

An easy question I am having a difficult time finding a straightforward answer to.

The quotient $\frac{G}{C_G(P)}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(P)$ where $P$ is a group of prime order.

Is $|Aut(P)|=p-1$?

Comment: Hint: Any automorphism of such a group has the form $x\mapsto x^m$ for a suitable $m$. Which $m$ will give automorphisms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's try to demonstrate that every group of order $p$ in cyclic.

Then it's easy to prove that the only automorphisms of $P$ are defined by $\phi(g)=g^k$, where $g$ is a generator of $P$ and $(k,p)=1$.

It's now easy to check that $Aut P \simeq \left(\mathbb{Z}_p\right)^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$

Comment: That last equality is not at all as trivial as the rest (though it is certainly a well-known fact). Also, it ought to be just an isomorphism.

Comment: I see. The Euler totient function gives the number of automorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Any group of prime order is cyclic, so every automorphism is of the form $x \to x^m$ for some $m > 0$. These aren't always automorphisms in all cyclic groups, but since our group has prime order they are. Now you just need to figure out how any of these are actually different automorphisms.

Comment: Not all $m>0$ will give automorphisms. Some of them will give the trivial map.

Comment: Hah whoops. I forgot about those. The idea is still the same though.